# Pass password as variable in bash ldapquery

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

Context: I am writing a short script, where I am fetching password from AWS secret manager storing it as variable and passing it to ldapquery argument.

Problem: It is throwing invalid creds as output, even tough the password is right. I tried escaping the special characters but nothing works

Script

```
#!/bin/bash


# Use jq to extract the password from the JSON output
LDAP_PASSWORD=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id SECRET_ID --query SecretString --output text --profile PROFILE1 | jq -r '.["KEY"]') 

ldapsearch -x -H ldap://10.91.10.10 -D ldap.query@at.prod.mango.local -w '$LDAP_PASSWORD' -b "OU=mango,DC=at,DC=prod,DC=mango,DC=local" "(objectClass=computer)" cn
```

example password is similar to : )AB#2Mn!5!1a

This works :

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://10.91.10.10 -D ldap.query@at.prod.mango.local -w ')AB#2Mn!5!1a' -b "OU=mango,DC=at,DC=prod,DC=mango,DC=local" "(objectClass=computer)" cn
```

Comment: Double quotes, surely? Otherwise the $variable won't be expanded. Off topic.

Comment: Double quotes won't work in my case, cause variable has special characters in it. I tried escaping those with ```\``` but still no luck

Comment: Eh? The double quotes are around `$LDAP_PASSWORD`, and then substitution happens. What's the problem with the substitution containing special characters?

Comment: Do it as `-w "$LDAP_PASSWORD"`. But don't forget that this makes the password publically visible to everyone with the permission of doing a `ps` of all processes. Perhaps using `-y` would be a better idea.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really test this as I don't have access to an LDAP server atm, but try this:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Use jq to extract the password from the JSON output
LDAP_PASSWORD=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id SECRET_ID --query SecretString --output text --profile PROFILE1 | jq -r '.["KEY"]') 

ldapsearch -x -H ldap://10.91.10.10 -D ldap.query@at.prod.mango.local -w "'"$LDAP_PASSWORD"'" -b "OU=mango,DC=at,DC=prod,DC=mango,DC=local" "(objectClass=computer)" cn
```

The single quotes definitely won't work around a variable, so you might need a 2nd set of doublequotes.

Comment: Same error, I have tried escaping the special characters. Wonder what is going wrong.

Comment: @zexapod  Does the edited version with the wrapped single quotes work?

Comment: @zexapod - ping :)